# Debug for a specific resolution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing the IHM for an application in C# forms with visual studio 2015. This application will run on a old computer with a resolution 1024x768.

Is there a way to run my application in this resolution ? I mean, only this application will run in 1024x768, I don't want to change my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code in your application to automatically change used resolution. An example can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx) (search for **Changing the Display Resolution**)

```
var display = new Display();
var settings = display.GetDisplaySettings();
var selectedMode = <get your resolution here>;
display.ChangeSettings(selectedMode);
```

(at the top of the article you can download all the examples provided in that article).

Ideally, you should store current resolution and automatically restore it on application exit.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to buy a old screen and test your app in it. An old 1024x768 screen will cost you like nothing.

You can also set a fixed size to your main window and remove borders, to simulate the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Doing so implies changing the settings to lower the resolution.

Comment: Well, no? For the first situation you can have full hd or better screen(s) for VS and another one with the lower resolution as asked. And for the second one, you can have your screen in FHD, and you app in fixed mode with window size of 1024x768. It will be a floating window, with correct size, on a bigger screen, so no resolution loweing is necessary.